# Ajax results, inserting to html elements in open modal with multiple array result rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page that is functional but I"m having an issue with Javascript inserting ajax results as html properly.

First of all, the page right now has a table with multiple rows, each row having it's own hyperlink. Clicking the link pops up a modal, makes an ajax call to get data, and the idea is that two values from the data result get inserted into h2 elements. Currently, I get my ajax result and it appends the first row since I"m using `data[0]` but I need this to work so that if my ajax result has 4 rows, I would append 4 sets of h2 elements. Also, since I'm using a modal that is based on any of the available links, I need to make sure it's appending only to the open modal if that makes sense?

Anyway, I just need to slightly alter this so that it appends to the open modal with the newest ajax results regardless of one or mulitple array rows in the result.

```
    <table class="uk-table uk-table-hover">
    <tbody>
        @foreach($results as $result)

        <tr class="" id="">
            <td>
                <a onclick="getDetails('{{$result->detailID}}')" data-toggle="modal" data-id="{!! $result->detailID !!}" data-uk-modal="{target:'#resultModal{{$result->detailID}}'}">{{$result->number}}</a>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <!------------- MODALS ------------->
        <div id="resultModal{{$result->detailID}}" class="uk-modal">
            <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
                <a class="uk-modal-close uk-close"></a>
                <form method="POST" action="/tasks/complete" class="uk-form uk-form-stacked uk-margin-top">
                    <div class="uk-grid">
                        <div class="uk-form-row uk-width-1-1">
                            <h3>{{$result->number}} - {{$result->name}}</h3>
                            <h2 class="detailSite"></h2>
                            <h2 class="detailType"></h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
    </table>

    <!-- End container -->
    </div>
    @endsection


    <script type="text/javascript">
        Vue.component('modal',{
            template: '#modal-template'
        })

        new Vue({
            el:'#app',
            data: {
                showModal: false
            }
        })
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getDetails(detailID) {
        console.log(detailID);
      $.ajax({
        url: "/details",
        data: {detailID:detailID},
        _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            $('.detailType').html(data[0].detail_type);
            $('.detailSite').html(data[0].detail_site);
        },
      });
    };

    </script>

    @endsection
```